# computed field to display latest addition to form or view

Tags: xpages

I would like to find a way to get the unid of the latest document added to a certain Form(View) from another nsf file (not the current one).

**EDIT**

I made a view with first column , @Created , descending

Then I tried :

```
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("", "product/picture.nsf");
if (db == null) {
     return "Database not open";
} else {
     var unid = db.GetView("pictures4").getFirstDocument().getUniversalID();
     return unid;
}
```

This gives me an error :

[TypeError] Error calling method 'GetView(string)' on an object of type 'lotus.domino.local.Database [Static Java Interface Wrapper, lotus.domino.local.Database: lotus.domino.Database]'

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a view in the other id that shows the UNID of all documents in question in desc order
Use session.getDatabase() (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/NotesSession_sample_JavaScript_code_for_XPages#getDatabase) to open the other database.
Open the view and navigate to the first document in the view. You can choose on your own, wether to use a Viewnavigator and get the value by reading the column value or opening the documnet and return the UNID

Answer (score 1):

A few points here.

1) The error message you're getting is that there is an error calling GetView() in NotesDatabase. Methods in SSJS are case-sensitive and always camelcase. GetView() method doesn't exist. You need getView().

2) Your code will throw an error if the database is not at that location. getDatabase(String, String) returns a NotesDatabase object that is not open. To return null, you need the third parameter, so getDatabase(String, String, boolean) using false. Check out the Domino Designer Help on the topic.

3) getDatabase("", "product/picture.nsf") may throw different results for XPiNC and web. In XPiNC I believe "" means local server - it does for @DbLookup. It's best to get into the practice of using getDatabase(database.getServer(), "product/picture.nsf").

Comment: Thanks Paul , I changed "" to database.getServer()

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest next:

1. make first column of view (lets call this view 'ByDate') sorted by 'Created Date' by descending.
2. then you need to do something like that:

   - init database where you want to get last document unid: session.getDatabase(server, filepath)
   - var unid = NotesDatabase.GetView("ByDate").getFirstDocument().getUniversalID()

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this

1. Use the getModifiedDocuments method of the database class to do this
2. Do a search in db2 based on creating date
3. Find or create a view in db2 that contains the document and is  sorted descending and use view.getFirstDocument()

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

have you tried
     var unid = db.getView("pictures4").getFirstDocument().getUniversalID();
instead of
     var unid = db.GetView("pictures4").getFirstDocument().getUniversalID();
?